# How to Get Multiple Images as Planes at Once

Tags: objects, import, image

[image]
I want to select multiple files in the Windows Explorer and drag and drop them into the blender to get multiple images as Planes.

But I basically notice that Blender creates one Reference object at a time or adds one Background Image in the camera view.

How do I manipulate the blender to achieve my desire? Or add-on?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This was a pretty dumb question.
I just need to select multiple images from the blender's file browser that appears when I run the Images as Planes command.